# PHP: One php file - many pages

Tags: php

I'm supposed to make 1 PHP file called "access.php" that contains 11 pages.  I have to do this with 1 PHP file.  I'm supposed to accomplish this using functions to display each page.  The "welcome" page allows a user to select "Administrator" or "User" via radio button.  After hitting submit, the corresponding page should appear.  Right now the admin/user page functions simply echo "Administrator Page" or "User Page" for testing purposes.

Ideally, a new page should appear that displays one of those centered at the top of the screen.  But what's happening right now is the text "Administrator Page/User Page" just appears at the bottom of the welcome screen.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
#---Functions---

#**PHP Header**
#function phpHeader(){
#print <<< EOF
#<!DOCTYPE html> 
#<head> 
#</head>
# <body>
#EOF
#}

#**PHP Footer**
#function phpFooter() {
#echo "</body> </html>";
#}

#**Admin Page**
function adminPage(){
#phpHeader();

echo "<center><h1>Administrator Page</h1></center>";

#phpFooter();
}

#**User Page**
function userPage(){
#phpHeader();

echo "<center><h1>User Page</h1></center>";

#phpFooter();
}

#**Welcome Page**
function welcomePage(){
#phpHeader();

echo "<center><h1>Welcome</h1>";
echo "<br><br><br>";
echo "<h3> Select Login Type</h3>";
echo "<br><br><br>";

echo '<form name="access" action="" method="post">';
echo '<input type="radio" name="AccessLevel" value="admin" />Administrator <br />';
echo '<input type="radio" name="AccessLevel" value="user" /> User <br /><br />';
echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose Level" />';
echo '</form></center>';

$AccessLevel = $_POST['AccessLevel'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (! isset($AccessLevel)) {
    echo '<h2>Select an option </h2>';
    }
    elseif ($AccessLevel == "admin") {
    adminPage();
    }
    else {
    userPage();
    }

}
#phpFooter();
}

welcomePage();

?>
```

Comment: **A:** Your code block's in the wrong spot.

Comment: Yes. It's homework.  I'm not looking for a direct answer - just something to get me going.  I may sound like a "typical" student when I say this, but:  My prof DID NOT cover PHP very well.  I mean I respect the "teach yourself" method, but I'm fairly sure he didn't explain this or even give examples.

Comment: Fred, are you saying that you declare functions at the bottom in PHP?

Comment: No, I mean place this entire block `$AccessLevel = $_POST['AccessLevel'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (! isset($AccessLevel)) {
    echo '<h2>Select an option </h2>';
    }
    elseif ($AccessLevel == "admin") {
    echo adminPage();
    }
    else {
    userPage();
    }

}` at the top of your page if you wish the message to appear "on top".

Comment: Well what I really need is for the welcome page to disappear and have either admin page or user page be the only thing shown - as if it were an entirely new page.

Comment: Add `return;` or `exit;` --- `$AccessLevel = $_POST['AccessLevel'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (! isset($AccessLevel)) {
    echo '<h2>Select an option </h2>';
    }
    elseif ($AccessLevel == "admin") {
    echo adminPage();
return;
    }
    else {
    userPage();
return;
    }

}` - or even `die();`

Comment: I posted an answer below, it reads better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this entire block at the top of your page, right under your opening `<?php` tag.

Sidenote: You can use `return;` or `exit;` or `die();`, the choice is yours; I used `return;`

```
$AccessLevel = $_POST['AccessLevel'];
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    if (! isset($AccessLevel)) {
    echo '<h2>Select an option </h2>';
    }
    elseif ($AccessLevel == "admin") {
    echo adminPage();
return;
    }
    else {
    userPage();
return;
    }

}
```

Which will echo only "Administrator Page" or "User Page" at the top of the page and nothing else.

Comment: Alright, this is looking good...I'm almost there.  I've basically got this working, but I have (hopefully) one final inquiry...When I start adding more IF statements for processing input from more pages, how do the IFs keep from "bumping into" one another?  Will I just use different form/radio button/submit button names?

Comment: @Shane They shouldn't bump into each, just as long at you're using unique function names, and that the conditional statements and POST variables match and are uniquely named, just as you have them now. Just follow the same pattern, but use unique names.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

function adminPage(){

    return "<center><h1>Administrator Page</h1></center>";

}

function userPage(){

    return "<center><h1>User Page</h1></center>";

}

function welcomePage(){

    return '<center><h1>Welcome</h1>
<br><br><br>
<h3> Select Login Type</h3>
<br><br><br>
<form name="access" action="" method="post">
<input type="radio" name="AccessLevel" value="admin" />Administrator <br />
<input type="radio" name="AccessLevel" value="user" /> User <br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Choose Level" />
</form></center>';

}


$AccessLevel = $_POST['AccessLevel'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    if(!isset($AccessLevel)){
        echo welcomePage();
    }elseif($AccessLevel=="admin"){
        echo adminPage();
        echo welcomePage(); // if you want to repeat that content at the bottom again
    }elseif($AccessLevel=="user"){
        echo userPage();
        echo welcomePage(); // if you want to repeat that content at the bottom again
    }
}else{//no form submitted

 echo welcomePage();

}

?>
```

Comment: Btw, you missed `()` ;)

Comment: sorry they fell behind the couch. Found the stray semi-colon from last week there to

Comment: Good thing the cat didn't get to 'em.

Comment: I'm going to try this shortly. Functions are a weakness of mine.  Forgot about returns and I guess I didn't know you could "echo" a function lol.  So this method will print an entire new page?

Comment: When I do the return - what if I had multiple lines? Like on my welcome page - do I add "return" in front of each line?  Or is there a way to return several lines at once?

Comment: html ignores your line beaks, just put it all inside the quotes

Comment: created a more  developed script

Comment: I don't know if I've messed something up, but I'm not getting any output using this method.  And when I view page source, no code is shown

Comment: edited, you need to catch the start point when no form has been submitted. i actully think you should give up on this approach, one file is a bitch to manage

Comment: Lol, I'm starting to notice that.  Well I have your method working now - with the IF statement outside of the welcome page function.  How is this going to work later on when I need to have more IFs - like once you get into the Admin page, there will be other options to select.  How do the IFs keep from getting into each others way? Will this be one giant IF statement OR several small IFs?  Will this involve giving my submit and radio buttons different names on each page?

Comment: there are many fine opensource easy to use CMS that you could install